# Creating subcollection in Firestore generates two documents with same id (rather than updating the pre-existing document)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the set method as following:

```js
admin.firestore()
  .collection('threads')
  .doc(threadId)
  .collection('posts')
  .doc(postId)
  .set(data);
```

Doing the following works, but it generates another document with the exact same id, and no data (just the sub-collection in it), rather than adding a sub-collection to the original document.

Here is a screenshot of my root collection (threads) after the set() method call :
[image]

The document with id in italic doesn't contain any data but a sub-collection (with the correct document).

**What am I doing wrong here, and how can I ensure my actually existing document is updated ?**

Also I applied the same method to create documents in my thread collection (`db.collection('threads').doc(newThreadId).set(data)`) and worked like a charm, for both creating and updating existing documents.

Comment: What happens if you refresh the console page?

Comment: @DougStevenson Nothing, both documents remain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is still reading and writing document data as you expect, regardless of what you see in the console, then congratulations - you've found a bug in the Firebase console.  It's highly unlikely that your code or the SDK is doing anything wrong.

I suggest [contacting Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) and file a bug report with the steps you took that reproduce this situation.